# Fanpage/Application integration: how to post to a fan page from an application

Tags: facebook

I have an existing client who has a fan page for their brand already. I need to create a Facebook Connect enabled website (so I'll be creating an application for it). I want the Facebook Connect application to post to the Fan page's wall ***as*** the brand. Is this possible? Is there a way to associate an application with a Fan page if I was an admin of both? Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the old REST API (or old javascript SDK), the stream.publish method (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish) has a uid parameter. Set that as the id of the Fan page and that should write to Fan Page wall as the Fan Page.

**Note:** you'll need to pass in a session_key from one of the Page admins for it to work.

Comment: Do you think I'll need a "permanent" extended session key for that? The client has added me as an admin of the page, so I could get an extended session and use my own key, right?

Comment: Yep, just grant offline_access to the application from the account and that should give you a permanent key.